# Java ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception -

Tags: java, swing, indexoutofboundsexception

I have 2 panels in my form which bound to a parent panel which has its layout set to card layout.

In the `JFrame`'s constructor, a database operation is performed and data is taken and used to fill a `JList`.

Then when a user clicks on an item, a new panel ( as part of `CardLayout` ) shows up with a `JTable` filled with data taken from a database according to the selection made by the user in the listbox .

The program is basically a clinic management system.

In this `JFrame`, the cashier can see the id numbers of patients who are to pay their bills . These id numbers are displayed as a list in the `JList`.

On clicking the list, a patient id is selected and then the drugs prescribed are queried from the database and displayed in the table along with drug id & price.

The problem is that I get an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` whenever I try to add a row to the `JTable`.

These are declared outside the mouseclick event (globally)

```
private Connection medDbConn = Connect("medicines.db");
private PreparedStatement mPst = null;
private ResultSet mRs = null;

private Connection conn = Connect("bills.db");
private PreparedStatement pst = null;
private ResultSet rs = null;

private ArrayList medicines_fine = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList medicines_fine_name = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList medicines_fine_qty = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList medicines_id = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList medicines_price = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList medicines_subtotal = new ArrayList();

private Double cf = 0.00;
/**
 * Creates new form ViewBills
 */
private DefaultListModel listmodel;
private DefaultListModel model;
```

The following is executed in the mouseclick event of the `JList` .

```
        // GET SELECTED VALUE FROM LIST
    String listvalue = (String) jList1.getSelectedValue();

    // SPLIT THE SELECTED LIST VALUE INTO ID AND DATETIME
    String[] datas = listvalue.split("=");

    // datas[0] = id and datas[1] = datetime
    // STORE PATIENTID and DATETIME
    String Patient_Id = datas[0].trim();
    String DateTime = datas[1].trim();

    String medicines_raw = null;
    String[] medicines;
    String[] keypair;

    try {

        // CONNECT THE DATABASE & PREPARE IT . THEN SET THE VALUES & FURTHER EXECUTE QUERY TO GET RESULT INTO "rs"
        pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT CONSULTFEE,MEDICINES FROM VIEWBILLS WHERE ID=? AND DATETIME=?");
        pst.setString(1, Patient_Id);
        pst.setString(2, DateTime);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        // IF THERE IS A RECORD , THEN DO SOMETHING
        if (rs.next()) {

            cf = rs.getDouble("consultfee");

            // GET THE RAW VALUE IN THE FORMAT Aspirin=12,sdsd=1,asdasd=2
            medicines_raw = rs.getString("medicines");

            // SPLIT THE WORD BY COMMAS AND STORE INTO ARRAY , SO EACH INDEX has Aspirin=12 kind of values
            medicines = medicines_raw.split(",");

            for (int i = 0; i < medicines.length; i++) {

                medicines_fine.add(medicines[i]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < medicines_fine.size(); i++) {
                keypair = medicines_fine.get(i).toString().split("=");

                medicines_fine_name.add(keypair[0]);
                System.out.println(keypair[0]);
                System.out.println(keypair[1]);
                medicines_fine_qty.add(keypair[1]);
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) Parent.getLayout();
    cl.show(Parent, "card3");

        // SECOND DATABASE CONNECTION STARTS HERE ...

    for (int i = 0; i < medicines_fine_name.size(); i++) {
            try {

                pst = medDbConn.prepareStatement("SELECT ID,SELLPRICE FROM MEDICINES WHERE NAME=?");
                pst.setString(1, (String) medicines_fine_name.get(i));

                rs = pst.executeQuery();

                if (rs.next()) {

                    medicines_id.add(rs.getString("id"));
                    medicines_price.add(rs.getDouble("sellprice"));

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }

        for ( int i = 0; i < medicines_fine_name.size() ; i++) {
            tblmodel.addRow(new Object[] {medicines_id.get(i),medicines_fine_name.get(i),medicines_price.get(i),medicines_fine_qty.get(i)});
        }
    }
```

The whole thing sometimes run without error if the last for loop is removed . ( but that beats the purpose )

And Yeah , I said "sometimes" .. I am very much confused and as you can see, this code is written in a very ugly manner. I had written it the normal way, but this `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` made me re-write the whole code 3 time, which ended in me writing pretty bad & ugly code but with the error still hanging on.

Pls let me know if anything is still unclear
Edit1: Basically what i'm trying to do is from the selected string in jlist , separate the datetime part and id part using split() function and store them to an array . Then use this id and name to select medicines from database . "medicines" is a string containing comma separated values like Aspirin=2,Amoxylin=5,etc=2,etc=10 where =10 means 10 of them ( indicating quantity . Then the drug name is stored into an arraylist and qty into another . Then use this medicine_name to get the medicine_id and sellprice. Finally set all this into a table .

Comment: Stacktrace, please. And tell us, which line exactly produces the error.

Comment: Okay, out of context code, wall of explanation, no stack trace...we're off to a good start here

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: You're doing a lot of splits and blind assumptions on the result, it's likely that one of these don't hold a first or second value

Comment: I'm sorry for this foolish question but stacktrace means what you see in the output window when the error occurs  .

Comment: compare the size of medicines_id with medicines_fine_name. I think there would be a mismatch between the two and hence get(i) is throwing AIOOB exception.

Comment: @almas shaikh - that is something I forgot to ask . There is a mismatch , but this mismatch doesn't occur everytime . Anyway how can I clear this mismatch ? Basically what i'm trying to do is from the selected string in jlist , separate the datetime part and id part using split() function and store them to an array . Then use this id and name to select medicines from database . "medicines" is a string containing comma separated values like Aspirin=2,Amoxylin=5,etc=2,etc=10 where =10 means 10 of them ( indicating quantity . Then the drug name  is stored into an arraylist and qty into another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < medicines_fine_name.size() ; i++) {
        tblmodel.addRow(new Object[]   {medicines_id.get(i),medicines_fine_name.get(i),medicines_price.get(i),medicines_fine_qty.get(i)});
}
```

You are iterating over index in arraylist where there are no elements present.

What you are doing is you are firing two queries, in first query say you got 10 records.

Now in second query you iterate over your 10 records (processed and passed in arrayList from first query result) and fire in query 10 times. You may or may not get record and you do:

```
if (rs.next()) {
    medicines_id.add(rs.getString("id"));
    medicines_price.add(rs.getDouble("sellprice"));
 }
```

if out of 10 you get record for 5 then size of medicines_id, medicines_price arraylist would be just 5.

Now comes your final loop as above. Here in the for loop you try to iterate over medicines_id,medicines_fine_name,medicines_price,medicines_fine_qty until size of 10 as per first query (medicines_fine_name.size()).

so when your i goes to index 6, you try to get on say

```
medicines_id.get(6)
```

but this element you never populated as per your second query hence ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.

To fix this, one way would be to use else part to populate dummy value to id and price like below:

```
if (rs.next()) {
    medicines_id.add(rs.getString("id"));
    medicines_price.add(rs.getDouble("sellprice"));
 } else {
    medicines_id.add(rs.getString("9999"));
    medicines_price.add(rs.getDouble("10.00"));
 }
```